# How do I specify the amount of syrup taken from this bottle?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I order coffee with syrup the Barista takes the syrup from a bottle like this:

[image]

He pushes the pump down completely twice. This is too much syrup for me. I only want one complete push or even only half a push down.

**What is the word for the unit of pushing the pump down once?**

Example:

> I'd like a caramel macchiato. But with only half a _____ of syrup.

Comment: I often hear "shot" in this context.

Comment: "Pump" would suffice. I couldn't agree more with you, problemofficer - those syrups are far too sweet for two full pumps.

Comment: Moving away from the "technical" word, I tend to say "...a caramel macchiato, but with half the amount of sugar".  That way, even if they normally do 2 pumps, 6 pumps, etc. I don't have to know that to specify the amount of pumps.  Just specifying the percentage/amount more generally does it.  If I say "...with half the sugar", the barista tends to then say more specifically, "Is 1 [or however many] pump okay?".

Comment: You can also say "easy on the syrup" or "not too much syrup" or "half the usual amount of syrup."  The barrister will probably ask what you mean.

Comment: Although I've been told to say "1 pump", I usually say 1/2 the chocolate (I get mochas).  By the way, this makes a MUCH better mocha imo.

Comment: The answer to the title (and what you want) is, *easy on the [condiment].* If you want to talk about pumps from a squirt bottle, that's a different title, and then it's either a whole number or fraction…

Comment: Italian speaker and habitant: Syrup? In coffee? Black coffee with syrup? [*gags*] Is this *syrup, syrup* or "liquor"? A tipple of grappa and Sambuca is highly recommended

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can refer to a single "amount" as a **pump**.

> Each 7.5 oz. Dial® Liquid Hand Soap bottle provides about 125 **pumps** per bottle.

[Link](http://www.dialsoap.com/frequently-asked-questions)

Though its OED definition is a bit vague and not as strictly defined, you can find a justification for this usage of "pump" as "the amount produced by a single pumping action":

> 1.1 (in singular) An instance of moving something by or as if by a pump.
>       *‘the pump of blood to her heart’*

[Link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pump)

Though this speaks about the *general act* of pumping, rather than a countable noun.

However, it seems within the range of acceptability that the produced amount can be referred to by the act of pumping itself.

- **One** pump = the produced amount from pumping **once**.
- **Two** pumps = the produced amount from pumping **twice**.

It's shorthand for counting how often the act of pumping occurs. Similar usages can be found:

- Two **slices** of cheese (you slice **twice**)
- A **pinch** of salt (you pinch **once**)

However, for these examples, their nouns have been well-defined in the OED by now. I believe that the analogous "pump" simply has not been in common usage enough to warrant adding its definition to the OED.

But its correctness should be analogous to that of "slice" or "pinch". From the comment that was posted, "**squeeze**" and "**squirt**" are equally correct for the same reason: it uses the *act of doing something* to describe *the produced result from this act*.

Comment: Is "squeeze" and "sqiurt" also possible, as proposed by Max Williams? Is "pump" the technical term and the other two colloquial?

Comment: @problemofficer "squeeze" and "squirt" are equally fine. I think your comment just missed the update to my answer, which futher elaborates on why "pump" is not strictly defined as "the amount"; though it can be argued to be correct. I will add the other examples too, as they fit the bill rather nicely.

Comment: *Pump* is how my barista friend refers to it when she's explaining recipes.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use *squeeze* as it doesn't really describe what you're doing, but both *pump* and *squirt* are fine. I'd use the latter, as it feels better to me -- *pump* could (just about) be taken to mean pump-full, i.e. the entrie dispenser.

Comment: @ChrisH The reference is made to the act of pumping (verb), not the pump (noun). Pedantically looking at its definition, a pump is not even a container; in OP's picture the "pump" is limited to the black plastic tool, not the bottle that it is placed on. _"pump could (just about) be taken to mean pump-full"_ The only basis for your claim that it means "the whole bottle" would be that you consider the whole bottle as a pump (noun), which is simply not the case. A pump-full would describe the amount that you can pump _in a single go_, i.e. the "pump chamber", not the container it is connected to

Comment: I know the reference is to the verb -- but the noun is the same word.  And if you google "pump dispenser" you'll see lots of bottles.  Pedantically (your word) looking at a definition has little to do with everyday use.  It may be that *pump* is preferred in some places; IME *squirt* is more common in the UK (or *shot* which I'll answer with).

Comment: @ChrisH: _"And if you google "pump dispenser" you'll see lots of bottles."_ If you google "car" you see a lot of roads too. That's not an argument for the definition of the word. A pump is not a container, even though this type of pump usually is found attached to a container.

Comment: @Flater the search gives plenty of sales listings which clearly refer to the whole thing .This isn't a time to care what the dictionary says, it's a time to look at what real humans actually use

Comment: These dispensers have become ubiquitous in coffee shops where the near-universal term for the amount of one full depression of the device is *pump*. This is important in coffee orders because customers want to specify a fairly exact amount of whatever syrup they want. An order might ask for something like "two pumps caramel and one pump hazelnut" or something like that. I'm not a coffee drinker and I've always and only used *pump* for this, as in condiment and soap dispensers. My background is native AmE speaker in the mid-Atlantic region.

Comment: @ChrisH: "[number] pumps" is what real humans actually use. My answer started with an example of a usage. Hence my answer in the first place, the definition is only a further justification as to why this _actual usage_ can be considered correct (though not literally defined in the OED as such). My argument is based on real world usage.

Comment: @Flater real humans WHERE?

Comment: There's one benefit to specifying the number of pumps (as opposed to putting it into terms like "measure" or even "shot") which is particular to OP's case -- it appears that TWO pumps is the standard measure in this case.  Specifying a half-measure could be confusing, but saying a single pump is pretty clear (as is a single "squirt").

Comment: @ChrisH: Google search **"pumps of" coffee** (everything in bold, including the quotes for better results). Also note that I have come across zero instances where "a pump of" meant to empty the entire container. I'm eager to see an example of that in real world usage.

Comment: @Flater that's not relevant to my last question.  I;m out of here

Comment: The suggestion of "squirt" sounds most idiomatic to my Midwestern US ears. I would probably say "just one squirt" rather than "half a squirt" for what the OP describes, as I would interpret "half a squirt" to mean only depressing the pump halfway, rather than depressing it all the way one time. Including "just" should hopefully signal to the barista/o that  one wants less than the standard quantity.

Comment: One nice thing about *pump* over *squirt*: the former can be further divided, while the latter can't. e.g. "half a pump" is probably possible (unless you're using a pump designed to dispense exactly the same amount of liquid regardless of how hard/far you pump it), while "half a squirt" just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Um - "the pump of blood TO the heart"??

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru: I didn't write the example. It does sound weird now that you've pointed it out, but it is correct. Consider [coronary circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronary_circulation). A small part of the blood that gets pumped out into the aorta immediately splits off towards the heart. As the heart is a muscle, it also needs blood to work. So there is in fact blood that is pumped (by the heart) specifically towards the heart. E.g. a [myocardial infarction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocardial_infarction) is caused by issues with _the pump of blood to your heart_.

Comment: Starbucks calls these _pumps_, in the US at least. That's good enough for me. _Shot_, as far as I can tell, usually refers only to espresso shots.

Comment: @Flater yeah I'll go with that.

Answer (score 17):

Coffee shops in the UK tend to refer to a *shot* of syrup.

This presumably originated with the term for a measure of spirits, but is also used for a serving of espresso.  That's a similar volume to a serving of syrup so the it's not surprising that the use propagated.

Comment: It also (perhaps only coincidentally) alludes to the motion of the liquid as it's dispensed, which when pressurized by a pump tends to "shoot" out of the dispenser.